# Trouble starting up PHP 7 on WAMP

Tags: php, wamp, php-7

I run a WAMP server on my laptop, on which I do my dev work. I finally decided to try installing PHP 7, and rather than downloading and installing the latest version of WAMP, I thought I'd try to install it myself. I found a few guides on how to do it, tried to get together the info I could, and went through the processes. After much breaking of systems, I finally got WAMP running again with my current setup, with PHP 7 showing up as a valid version, but when I switch to it, Apache won't start. The error logs don't tell me anything useful (unless I'm misunderstanding them). Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Off-Topic: As a Windows lover, the biggest piece of advice someone can give you is: Don't use Windows as development environment. Setup a Vagrant Machine with any Linux and everything in your life will be easier.

Comment: I know I shouldn't, but I always worry my machine won't handle a virtual OS within it well. And I guess the whole trepidation of learning a whole new tool just to do something I'm already doing. Plus, if I setup a virtual linux box in my Windows, how do I actually test the output/server? Or am I asking a stupid question.

Comment: I had the same resistance in learning a new environment just to do what I already did, but if you ever needed to install a dll that doesn't come with Wamp, you know the pain. A virtual machine can hold up fine with just 768M ram if you don't have huge databases. You'd test the server with an ip, like 192.168.1.10/your-project-folder instead of localhost/your-project-folder

Answer (score 0):

There is really not enough info here to help us help you.

If you are using WAMPServer 2.5 then you can install WAMPServer 3.0.3 directly over 2.5 [Get it here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net)

If you are using a previous version of WAMPServer I suggest you install WAMPServer3.0.4 but first read this so you dont loose anything in the process http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606.

WAMPserver3 comes with many ADDON versions of Apache, PHP and MYSQL. The addons are simple to install as they just add to WAMPServer 3 nd are activated from the menus

Comment: I'm sorry. As someone not good at figuring out or fixing server problems, I'm not sure what information to provide. I'll throw the log output above, but not sure what other information I need to provide. And I know I can install a new version of WAMP over it, but I want to improve my server/config knowledge, so thought I should try setting it up myself.

Comment: And as one trial before, now nothing is being written to the error logs. So now I have absolutely no idea what information I can provide; there are no logs being written over whatever is going wrong.

Comment: Try looking at the Windows Event Viewer for messages from `Apache`

Comment: This post on the [WAMPServer forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,135246,135248#msg-135248) might help you fix your issues